# Shiny checkboxGroupInput checkbox and label cannot be aligned

Tags: css, r, shiny

I tried to put a checkboxGropInput within a box, but I can't get the checkbox and label aligned (please see the screenshot, CSS, and R code below). Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
box(
        id = "page1_chkbox",
        headerBorder = F,
        collapsible = FALSE,
        width = 12,
        checkboxGroupInput(
            inputId = "qset1",
            label = "",
            choiceNames = c("Option 1 Option 1Option 1Option 1Option 1Option 1",
                            "Option 2 Option 2Option 2Option 2Option 2Option 2Option 2",
                            "Option 3 Option 3 Option 3 Option 3 Option 3 Option 3 Option 3 Option 3 ",
                            "Option 4 Option 4 Option 4 Option 4 Option 4 Option 4 Option 4 Option 4 Option 4 Option 4 "
          ),
          choiceValues = c(1,2,3,4)
        )
)
```

CSS:

```
#page1_chkbox {
  font-size: 25px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none; 
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left:5%;
  display: inline-table;
  align-items: baseline;
  justify-content: center;
  
}

#page1_chkbox input[type=checkbox] {
    transform: scale(3);
}

#page1_chkbox span { 
    margin-left:50px;
    text-align: start;
    text-align-last: start;
display: inline-table;
}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Try `label = NULL`.

Comment: Code is not reproducible

Comment: I finally decide to put all checkboxes on a table.